# Different info for different pin annotations

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, segue, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I have two different pins placed on my mapview. I have an info button on each. The info buttons will segue to the a UIViewController that has a Image view (to hold a picture of the place) and a Text label ( To hold info about the place).

My problem is how can I generate the Info and picture depending on which pin annotation button was selected. The last function is the one used in order to segue to the info view controller.

```
  class GetToTheStart: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
//map view outlet
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

//defining use of location manager
let myLocMgr = CLLocationManager()




     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //setting up location request
    myLocMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    myLocMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    myLocMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    myLocMgr.delegate = self
    mapView.delegate = self

    // coordinates of desired locations for pins 
    var zoo1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.347439, -6.291820)
    var town1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.347247, -6.290865)

    //setting up pin 1 annotation (the zoo) 
    var zoopin = MKPointAnnotation()
    zoopin.coordinate = zoo1
    zoopin.title = "Dublin Zoo"
    zoopin.subtitle = "This this the zoo"
    mapView.addAnnotation(zoopin)

    //setting up pin 2 annotation (the town) 
    var townpin = MKPointAnnotation()
    townpin.coordinate = zoo1
    townpin.title = "Dublin town"
    townpin.subtitle = "This this the town"
    mapView.addAnnotation(townpin)
 }


   //setting up Pin callout button for segue
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    }
    let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
    var pin =    mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pin == nil {
        pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        pin!.pinColor = .Red
        pin!.canShowCallout = true
        pin!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    } else {
        pin!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return pin
}



   //performing segue from info button to infoViewController
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("info", sender: view)
}
```

Comment: While giving code, format it well otherwise it will be very difficult to go through it...

Comment: When you click on the pin you need to know which pin annotation is clicked either pin with title "Dublin Zoo" or "Dublin town"? Is this your problem?

Comment: Reformatted it there and added a few comments so it should be easier to follow. Yes the problem is I cannot figure out how to send information only about the pin that is clicked (i.e. either the zoo pin or the town pin) to the infoViewController.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to override below method. Here we will get the annotationView which will trigger the segue.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "info") {
        if let annotation = sender as? MKAnnotationView {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
            detailViewController.titleText  = annotation.annotation?.title ?? ""
            detailViewController.detaileText = annotation.annotation?.subtitle ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

And in the detailViewController is same as your infoViewController and here I have two labels and for that I have two public variables. This is just to avoid error because at this point we don't have the label objects.

Here is the code for my DetailViewController.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!


var titleText: String? { didSet { updateUI() } }
var detaileText: String? { didSet { updateUI() } }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
}

private func updateUI() {
    self.titleLabel?.text = self.titleText
    self.detailLabel?.text = self.detaileText
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful in being able differentiate between the various pins. However this way only will only send the title and subtitle. Is there a way of linking a paragraph of information with each pin and displaying that? I was thinking of just setting the subtitle as the paragraph of information and and just hiding it from the annotation, what would you think?   is it possible to link an image with each pin using this method?

Comment: Can you be more specific.. I'm not getting

Comment: Cool. Okay so the code that you posted enables the title and subtitle of the selected pin to be sent to the infoViewController. This is very helpful. However I would like to send a paragraph about the selected pin to the infoViewController, not just the title and subtitle of the pin. I would also like to have a picture associated with each pin and be able to send this to the infoViewController as well as the paragraph.

Comment: cool how could that be done as it is not a annotation.annotation?.title ?? or annotation.annotation?.subtitle ??.